# How to reverse a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack-overflow

I was working on Stack Overflow and came up across the #92.

> Reverse a linked list 2 question. This is the question's description:
> Given the head of a singly linked list and two integers left and right
> where left <= right, reverse the nodes of the list from position left
> to position right, and return the reversed list. For example, given
> the linked list [1,2,3,4,5] 1, 4 the list should become [4,2,3,1,5]

It works for all runs but my code produces the wrong answer for one test case, which doesn't make sense. given. [1,2,3,4] 1,4  with 1 being left position an 4 being right position what makes sense for the list to become is [4,2,3,1] which is what my code produces. The correct answer they display is [4,3,2,1] which is screwing with my head and I can't understand why it's doing that. Any heads up are appreciated.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) 
    {
        int x = 1;

        ListNode * left_node = nullptr;
        ListNode * right_node = nullptr;
        ListNode * curr = head;
        int temp = 0;
                
        if (!head)
            return nullptr;
        
        while(curr)
        {
            if(x == left)
                left_node = curr;
                
            if(x == right)
                right_node = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            ++x;
        }
        
        temp = left_node->val;
        left_node->val = right_node->val;
        right_node->val = temp;
     
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5] 1, 4 - position(1) is "2", position(4) is "5". Reversing from position left to position right would be [1,5,4,3,2]. No? Or, if we don't consider the start and end, then it would be [1,2,4,3,5]. What am I missing? I don't understand how the result is [4,2,3,1,5]. Or are you counting indexes starting from 1 and no 0?

Comment: @Fra93 Yes, `left` and `right` are 1-based indices.

Comment: Right, then the answer should be [4,3,2,1,5] and the example in the question is wrong.

Comment: @Fra93 Yes, `[4,2,3,1,5]` for `[1,2,3,4,5] 1, 4` looks terribly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution implements swapping the values for the 2 indexes left and right, which matches the example given in the question.

But the question was to reverse the list between left and right, not just swap the two end points. So `1,2,3,4` becoming `4,3,2,1` is the correct solution and both the example and your solution are wrong, they only swap the endpoints.

PS: most languages start counting at 0.

Answer (score 1):

@Goswin Von Brederlow has already pointed out what is wrong, I will add a visual representation of what you are doing. Can you spot the problem?

[image]

EDIT: You can look in the comments for a better solution in terms of time and space (and also for a worse one).

After the while you should traverse the linked list. Since you don't have a "prev" (no double linked list) you need to traverse it multiple times to reverse it. I prepared a visualization of the algo, which uses a copy from left to right. And a support `node` for the prev node at each iteration. It uses `idx` and `oidx` to keep track of the position in the original and copied list.

[image]

And here are the steps of the iteration:

[image]

Comment: I would have visualized reversing the list as turning the pointers around 180° as you traverse it and then stiching it all back together when hitting the right mark. It can be all done in a single pass.

Comment: That's also an idea, another would be to create an array from LEFT -> RIGHT of the linked list, reverse the array, overwrite the linked list from LEFT -> RIGHT with the array content

Comment: what a waste of memory and time. That would take 4 passes.

Comment: Absolutely, but OP is learning and I think visualizing more than one solution could be helpful :) anyway, no need to be rude Goswin.

Comment: Didn't try to be rude. It's just a big step back from the algorithm you initially described that does 2 passes with 0 extra memory. Speaking of which you say "which uses a copy from left to right". I would uses the word "swap" there as you exchange the values of `*odix` and `*idx` in each step.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll update the answer.